# How to use other projects nuget packages as DLL C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll, nuget-package

I made my own Dll project, which includes a standard libraries like:
sstream
string
codecvt
fstream
iostream
string
etc. **(non-3-party libraries)**

and **opencv4.2 (3-party library)** which was installed through "Manage Nuget Packages" in Visual Studio.

After building it (creating the Dll and lib files) I linked to it from project, which is made to test the functionality of the dll. The project can't find opencv's libraries.

So I'm curious how to tell the testing project to include the nuget packages from Dll's project.

**Note that installing opencv again through "Manage Nuget Packages" to testing Project helps, but it is not an option in my case.**

Comment: `The project can't find opencv libraries.` What is the error message?

Comment: **fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory.** I found that my Dll project creates Dll's of the opencv, but it creates it separately from the main Dll and  including it to testing project doesn't help.

Comment: Try adding opencv2 directory in your testing project `C++>general > additional include directories`.

Comment: In addition, opencv4.2 opencv_world420d.lib  and dll are provided when installed in folder: opencv4.2.XXXXX\build\native\x64\vc15